# Looking for a way to pause or quiesce a database on google cloud platform

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to pause or quiesce a database on google cloud platform to reduce costs yet maintain the data?

If not, do any of the cloud database providers offer such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can [stop](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance#stop) a Cloud SQL instance. This will drop the instance charges but not the storage as you'll continue to work with the same database, once the instance is re-started.